# How to expand definition before giving it as argument to exsheet environment

Tags: macros

I'm trying to write exercise sheets in a modular way:
Each exercise has its own file with question/solution environments as provided by the `exsheets` package.

The exercise sheets then `\input`s the needed exercise.
The trouble is that I want to be able to decide, in each exercise sheet, whether or not I want to print the solutions.
The `exsheets` package helps with that since you can give `solution` environments the `print=true/false` option.

So, I naturally tried setting a variable in my exercise sheet file, variable that would be read by each solution environment to decide if it should be printed or not, but it doesn't work, since I think the parameter given is not expanded early enough.

Here would be a MWE for the sheet file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\def\printsolutions{true}

\begin{document}
    Some text.  
    \input{Exercise1}
\end{document
```

and here an exercise:

```
\begin{question}
    Question
\end{question}
\begin{solution}[print=\printsolutions]
    Solution
\end{solution}
```

And the problem now is that latex complains that the option given to `print` is not a valid choice:

```
! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-choice-unknown"
! 
! Key 'exsheets/solution/print' accepts only a fixed set of choices.
```

How should that be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a command that can set the correct key:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{exsheets}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\setsolutionprint { m }
{
 \keys_set:nn { exsheets / solution}{ print = #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

    Some text.
\setsolutionprint{true}

    \input{exercise1}

\end{document}
```

### Attention:

exsheets doesn't work with a current expl3 version. See https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues/44/error-latex3-error-variant-form-n

Comment: That works fine, thanks!
Two questions if I may:
1) What does the "m" stand for in the \NewDocumentCommand line? It doesn't seem to get used anywhere…
2) Can one use \setsolutionprint multiple time in the same document to selectively set it to true/false at different times?

Comment: 1) m stands for the mandatory argument (the `#1` used later), 2) try it out.

Comment: 2) it does :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here would be a MWE for the sheet file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\def\printsolutions{true}

\begin{document}
    Some text.  
    \input{Exercise1}
\end{document}
```

and here an exercise:

```
\begin{question}
    Question
\end{question}
\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\printsolutions]}{\begin{solution}[print=}%
    Solution
\end{solution}
```